# queue rich:autocomplete change events before sending them to the server

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I'm using the autocomplete component from richfaces. (the mode **has** to be ajax).
I have the following requirement: after the user types something in it the request should no go directly to the server, instead it should wait a period of, lets say 500 ms, before the autocomplete method gets called. This is to prevent ajax flooding (for example if the user types fast 3 chars it will only make one request to the server instead of 3). 
Basically I want the autocomplete method to get invoked only if 500 ms have passed from the last keystroke.
Of course this could be solved by using an a4j:queue, the problem is that the suggestions list always appears and the autocomplete method always get invoked regardless of what I use to prevent it (attaching an a4j:queue or setting frequency, eventsQueue & requestDelay attributes).
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency tag you mentioned is the way to do it. It is defined as: Delay (in seconds) before activating the suggestion pop-up. Default value is 400ms.

If you're setting your frequency to 500ms that is still too short: the user can type more than 1 characters in that time period, which is probably causing your ajax flood.

I suggest you set the frequency to **1000** or better yet **2000**.